# Can I put a figure with caption and label inside a theorem (newmdtheoremenv)?

Tags: floats, theorems

The following MWE doesn't compile if I uncomment the commented lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{theoremSty}{backgroundcolor=yellow!10, linewidth=0pt, innerleftmargin=3ex, innerrightmargin=3ex, innertopmargin=1ex, innerbottommargin=1ex, innermargin =+1cm, outermargin =+1cm}
\newcounter{theoremCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{theoremCounter}{chapter}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=theoremSty]{theorem}[theoremCounter]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}

\lipsum[1]

%\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
%  \caption{Example image A.}
%  \label{fig:example-image-a}
%\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The question is **why** can't I put the figure inside the theorem and **if** there is a workaround.

(I've checked that the figure works outside the theorem.)

Comment: You can have picture inside theorem, however not as float! The float `figure` is intended for move around in a text (therefore name *float*), what can not do inside theorem. If you like have the caption, than use `caption-of` from package `caption` or small package `capt-of``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with `\usepackage{floatrow}` that defines a new Option `H`
for `\begin{figure}[H]`.

With this, the figure is not floating and just placed where you include it.

You can use caption and label like for floating figures.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\mdfdefinestyle{theoremSty}{backgroundcolor=yellow!10, linewidth=0pt, innerleftmargin=3ex, innerrightmargin=3ex, innertopmargin=1ex, innerbottommargin=1ex, innermargin =+1cm, outermargin =+1cm}
\newcounter{theoremCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{theoremCounter}{chapter}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=theoremSty]{theorem}[theoremCounter]{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
%  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  THE IMAGE
  \caption{Example image A.}
  \label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{theorem}

Have a look at fig. \ref{fig:example-image-a}.

\end{document}
```

[image: document]